# Test changes necessary to upload Appium script to MS App Center

Tags: appium, visual-studio-app-center

Newbie here and needing help to make the necessary test changes in order to prepare upload of script to MS App Center

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/preparing-for-upload/appium